# Jquery code, not understanding properly

Tags: jquery

I am very new to web design and I am struggling in understanding the following jQuery code.

On my index.html page I have two links one called smaller the other bigger.

```
function change_size(element,size){
    var current = parseInt(element.css('font-size'));
    if(size =='smaller'){
        var new_size = current - 2;
    } else if (size=='bigger'){
        var new_size = current + 2;
    }

    element.css('font-size', new_size + 'px');
}

$('#smaller').click(function(){
    change_size($('p') 'Smaller'); /// function call 
});
$('#bigger').click(function(){
    change_size($('p') 'bigger');
});
```

Does the `element.css()` line at the end of the first function add `font-size` to `new_size` and then append "px" to it?

Comment: also if someone could explain parseInt, i looked it up but its confusing

Comment: This is not a question you will have to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: The MDN docs are good: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Basically it explicitly turns a string into a number value.

Comment: Oh I see that now I apologize I missed it in my first read through.  Thank you @Rup

Comment: Also `var` in JavaScript is odd, but for clarity I think you ought to declare it once above the `if`, i.e. `var new_size;` and then just set `new_size = ` in the branches. Also the smaller is probably case sensitive so you'll need the lower-case-S in your call (plus some extra commas).

Comment: You have also typos in your code, like: `change_size($('p') 'Smaller');` should be `change_size($('p'), 'smaller');` - notice comma and lower case letter of word `smaller`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates a function `change_size` which receives 1 or more jQuery objects (in this case whatever matches `$('p')`) and depending on the string passed to the function (either `Smaller` or `bigger`) it'll change the font size. The function is triggered by clicking either the elements `$('#smaller')` or `$('#bigger')`. Also what `parseInt()` does is parse a string argument and return an integer, you can find [**more info on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Finally, the function could be optimized to:

```
function change_size(element,size){
    var dif;
    if(size =='smaller'){
        dif = -2;
    } else if (size=='bigger'){
        dif = 2;
    }
    element.css('font-size','+='+dif);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` is for converting (casting) string value to an integer.

First If statement check what is passed to Size variable.

`element.css('font-size'` is accessing font-size css property of the element. If you pass 1 parameter to thefunction element.css, it will return property value, if you pass two parameter, it will set the value.

`$('#smaller')` is for getting reference of element with id smaller and .click attaches function on click

Go to JQuery tutorials for better understanding.